# How to make the Text take all the space in the container

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

In the above image,
If FittedBox is used then text is aligning and sizing itself only in the horizontal shape.

If FittedBox is not used then the text is flowing out of container

How to dynamically change size of the text, so the text takes all the available space

```
Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6,
                  child: FittedBox(
                    child: Text(
                      "Click Here Click Here Click Here Click Here Click Here Click Here Click Here ",
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 60,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given infinite width to the container, you should be giving it a width then the text component will automatically wrap.

```
Container(
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
...
```

Comment: It's same even after giving width, i gave width 100 and text is still in a single line